# How do I format a string in one cell to a number in another cell using a custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to take the string value of one cell and format it as a number in the cell with the function =makeNumber(value). So far this is my code:

```
function makeNumber(value){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    return ss.getRange(value).getDisplayValues().setNumberFormat("0.00");
}
```

It tells me that it can't find the object (string) in setNumberFormat. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: getrange will need range in string, for example A1:B1, can't accept other value for example numeric, date or string non range indicated

Comment: "ss.getRange(value)" is invalid syntax - refer [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: that function is just one part of your script? Because I don't understand what kind of type of variable should be ```value``` and why you're returning the result after formatting the cell. Do you want to use your function as a [Custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) ?